# org.json.JSONException: Value Dev of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-intent

Getting String cannot be converted to JSONObject

see below code:

**MainAdapter.java:-**

```
 HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

// Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AnotherActivity.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("name", resultp.get(MainActivity.NAME));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return itemView;
```

**AnotherActivity.java:-**

```
            String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

            jsonobject =  new JSONObject(value);
```

Comment: What you have is a string not a jsonobject. `resultp.get(MainActivity.NAME)` returns a string not a jsonobject i guess

Comment: Can you show your JSON string ? It is probably not a correctly formatted JSON string ...

Comment: yes you know everything bro

Comment: @Raghunandan as you said i am writing this as i think i can write and understand

Comment: @AbrahimNeil then if you know what's wrong you can fix it.

Comment: @Raghunandan not getting, but you know what i am trying to do ...

Comment: @AbrahimNeil i have already asnwered in full in your previous question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006448/multi-level-json-parsing

Comment: @AbrahimNeil Log the value of `resultp` and check the value

Comment: are you passing a JSON String in the intent??

Comment: Save string as - 
String value = "{\"name\":" + "\"" + getIntent().getStringExtra("name") +"\"}";

Comment: bro now getting thumb but not title @Raghunandan

Comment: @AbrahimNeil what more can i do other than show the full code and i even explained what was wrong before and what is there is my post to your previous question. Please re-read my answer in the previous post and follow it without any changes. It will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, provided by @Raghunandan

```
     JSONObject jb;
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AnotherActivity.class);
                jb = MainActivity.jsonarray.getJSONObject(position);
                intent.putExtra("name",jb.toString());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
 jsonobject =  new JSONObject(value);
```

The below line should work unless `value` is not a valid JSONObject. Check [this](http://json.org/example) for valid JSON formats