# How to parse the values present in JSON Array in this case

Tags: java

I am trying to Parse this JSON

```
{
    "details": {
        "Service Tax": [
            {
                "tax_order": 3,
                "inclusive": [
                    {
                        "Discount": 1,
                        "Service Charge": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "VAT": [
            {
                "tax_order": 3,
                "inclusive": [
                    {
                        "Discount": 1,
                        "Service Charge": 1,
                        "Item": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "vendor_id": 1
}
```

Is it possible to extract the fields for that value present in the array .

For example if it is **Service Tax , i need to fetch the Discount and Service Charge**

For example if it is **VAT , i need to fetch the Discount , Service Charge and Item**

```
package test;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Tester {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {

        String json = "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"details\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"Service Tax\": [\r\n" + 
                "            {\r\n" + 
                "                \"tax_order\": 3,\r\n" + 
                "                \"inclusive\": [\r\n" + 
                "                    {\r\n" + 
                "                        \"Discount\": 1,\r\n" + 
                "                        \"Service Charge\": 1\r\n" + 
                "                    }\r\n" + 
                "                ]\r\n" + 
                "            }\r\n" + 
                "        ],\r\n" + 
                "        \"VAT\": [\r\n" + 
                "            {\r\n" + 
                "                \"tax_order\": 3,\r\n" + 
                "                \"inclusive\": [\r\n" + 
                "                    {\r\n" + 
                "                        \"Discount\": 1,\r\n" + 
                "                        \"Service Charge\": 1,\r\n" + 
                "                        \"Item\": 1\r\n" + 
                "                    }\r\n" + 
                "                ]\r\n" + 
                "            }\r\n" + 
                "        ]\r\n" + 
                "    },\r\n" + 
                "    \"vendor_id\": 1\r\n" + 
                "}";


         String[] json_order = new String[]{"Service Tax", "VAT"};

            JSONObject inputRqstJson = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONObject details_json = inputRqstJson.getJSONObject("details");

                for(String tax_name : json_order)
                {
                JSONArray tax_nameJarray = details_json.getJSONArray(tax_name);
                System.out.println(tax_nameJarray);
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: Refer to this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006448/multi-level-json-parsing

Comment: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/135734/how-to-parse-multi-level-json-data - Answer in this link is good too

Comment: What do you want to *do* with the values once you've got them? It's really unclear at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet , Once i get them i want to store in a HashMap with String and ArrayList Combination .

Comment: That doesn't really give us much more information... but you might want to look at `JSONObject.keys()` to find out the keys for a particular object...